# Multi-Level donut Chart in R

Tags: r, pie-chart

I am trying to create a multi level donut pie chart in R, but having trouble. I am using matrix with three columns and seven rows. First column contains the labels (unique values), and then each label has two numerical values in the next two columns, revenue and profit.

```
print(DATA)
  PRODUCT  REV  PRO
1     GEN  40  50
2     PHA  20  20
3     FRE  10   9
4     JUM  10   5
5     PRC  15   2
6    POW    3   3
7     ALI   3  11
```

I want to make a two layer donut chart, with the first circle showing the revenue and the profit, same color for same label. Also I want the values in of each category in percentages. Something similar to this:

[image]